# Java Matcher not working for valid pcre pattern

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

Here is a working regex example https://regex101.com/r/wO3yP2/2

Here I am trying find if there is no invalid or failure in xml.

Here is the pattern **/^((?!INVALID|FAIL).)*$/i**

Here is the java class attempting to do the same thing, but cant find the match.

```
class RegexChecker {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String success = "this version has success in it";
        String reject = "this failure version doesnot have the s word in it";
        String falsePositive = "this version is invalid but still has success in it";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^((?!INVALID|FAIL).)*$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        Matcher successMatcher = pattern.matcher(success);
        if(successMatcher.find()){
            System.out.println("Success Matches");
        }
        Matcher rejectMatcher = pattern.matcher(reject);
        if(rejectMatcher.find()){
            System.out.println("Reject Matches");
        }
        Matcher falsePosMatcher = pattern.matcher(falsePositive);
        if(falsePosMatcher.find()){
            System.out.println("PseudoSuccess Matches");
        }
    }
}
```

How is java regular expression checker different than PCRE?

Comment: Even your regex101 demo is not finding any matches.

Comment: As for dialect differences, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) has a good overview (but your problem is not with that).

Comment: Here is a match for a string that doesnot contain **invalid** or **failure** -- https://regex101.com/r/wO3yP2/3

Comment: String with **failure** should not match - this failure version doesnot have the s word in it

Comment: String with **invalid** followed by **success** should not match - https://regex101.com/r/wO3yP2/5

Comment: @anubhava - please look at 3 links above. it will be clear

Comment: I believe [you need this regex](https://regex101.com/r/wO3yP2/6). This will behave same in PCRE or in Java

Comment: Why don't you try and _inverse_ the test instead?

Comment: @anubhava -- your regex works on regex101 but not in java code when i try to use it as below ```Pattern.compile("^(?!.*?\b(INVALID|FAIL)\b).*$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)``` It matches the strings containing invalid and fail.

Comment: @Amadan - My intention is to test the absence of Invalid or Fail anywhere in entire string. Also please look at the example link and you'll see that it works. http://regex101.com/r/wO3yP2/3

Comment: Sorry, missed the star.

Comment: After trying a few things and understanding what's going on with Anubhava's version I realized I dont need the word boundary because the string is a very long xml.  This pattern does what I intend to achieve ```^(?!.*?(INVALID|FAIL)).*$```. The way i read this pattern is --> for any character look ahead and fail if there is Invalid or fail preceded by zero or many of characters. However it doesnt make sense to me because here is my earlier pattern ```^((?!INVALID|FAIL).)*$``` which when read means for every character (including empty str) fail if INVALID or Fail is found anywhere in string

Comment: I would highly appreciate if some one can clarify why an extra .* in negative lookahead section would make a difference? for me both patterns are similar

Answer (score 0):

```
    String success = "this version has success in it";
    String reject = "this failure version doesnot have the s word in it";
    String falsePositive = "this version is invalid but still has success in it";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(INVALID|FAIL)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    Matcher successMatcher = pattern.matcher(success);
    if(successMatcher.matches()==false){
        System.out.println("Success Matches");
    }
    Matcher rejectMatcher = pattern.matcher(reject);
    if(rejectMatcher.find()){
        System.out.println("Reject Matches");
    }
    Matcher falsePosMatcher = pattern.matcher(falsePositive);
    if(falsePosMatcher.find()){
        System.out.println("PseudoSuccess Matches");
    }
```

Tried with the above program  got output as

Success Matches

Reject Matches

PseudoSuccess Matches

Is this the output you are expecting?

Comment: No this is not the output. I am trying to match a string that does not contain invalid or fail. If you use 3 links in comments you will see the result I desire.

Comment: Also matches() in your code must be find(). There is a difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around with code (thanks Anubhava for pattern) and reading here is what I need.

`^(?!.*?(INVALID|FAIL)).*$`

However, I have doubts about my earlier pattern. Please read comments on the questions where I have explained my doubts.

Comment: This is pretty much same as what I suggested to you and you commented that it doesn't work in Java.